# How can I modify this batch file so that it will add a number before the name of file and keep the caption as it is.?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    set /a i+=1

    ren "%%a" "!i!.new"
)
ren *.new *.jpg
```

I have this batch file to rename all files in folder as 1,2,3...n But the problem is its removing the caption, I want to modify it such that it will keep the caption as it is and will just add a number before a caption.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't know anything about this code, will you please modify it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For %%A In (*.jpg) do (Set /A i+=1      
    Ren "%%A" "!i!%%~nA.new"
)
Ren *.new *.jpg
```

The filename plus extension above is `%%A` and the filename without extension is `%%~nA`. So I  used `Ren "%%A" "!i!%%~nA.new"`. Please refer to the help usage of the `For` command for a full explanation, enter `For /?` at the Command Prompt to do so.

You can separate the `!i!` from the `%%~nA` with a character of your choosing too!

Comment: And what about If I want to add a space between the original cpation and the number which is going to be assigned by .bat file?

Comment: @Batman, why are you calling it a caption.  It is a file name. PERIOD! Compo clearly made a comment about adding extra characters within the file name.  It is literally the last line in his answer.  Make an attempt before asking another question.